# How to write a RegEx pattern that accepts a string with at most one of each letter, but unordered?

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

I have tried this:

```
[a]?[b]?[c]?[d]?[e]?[f]?[g]?[h]?[i]?[j]?[k]?[l]?[m]?[n]?[o]?[p]?[q]?[r]?[s]?[t]?[u]?[v]?[w]?[x]?[y]?[z]?
```

But this RegEx rejects string where the order in not alphabetical, like these:

- "zabc"
- "azb"

I want patterns like these two to be accepted too. How could I do that?

**EDIT 1**

I don't want letter repetitions, i.e., I want the following strings to be rejected:

- aazb
- ozob

Thanks.

Comment: like this `[a-z]?.....................`

Comment: No, @AvinashRaj. As I say in EDIT 1, and in the title, that I want at most one of each letter. No repetitions! Thanks, anyway. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to make sure no two characters are the same:

```
^(?!.*(.).*\1)[a-z]*$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^      # Start of string
(?!    # Assert that it's impossible to match the following:
 .*    # any number of characters
 (.)   # followed by one character (capture that in group 1)
 .*    # followed by any number of characters
 \1    # followed by the same character as the one captured before
)      # End of lookahead
[a-z]* # Match any number of ASCII lowercase letters
$      # End of string
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/eG5lH4/1).

Note: This regex needs to brute-force check *all* possible character pairs, so performance may be a problem with larger strings. If you can use anything besides regex, you're going to be happier. For example, in Python:

```
if re.search("^[a-z]*$", mystring) and len(mystring) == len(set(mystring)):
   # valid string
```

Comment: +1... Not obvious how this could be optimized to cut down on backtracking. Maybe a lazy quantifier on the first `.*`, otherwise we start with the last characters, where finding a failure case will take more time.

Comment: @zx81: I thought about that as well, but if we do that, then cases like `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyzz` take longer - so unless you can predict where the duplication will be more likely, you can't really choose an optimal regex.